# VSCode - Debuging/Launching using integrated Terminal instead Debug Console

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to use integrated Terminal for debugging/launching code instead of Debug Console in Visual Studio Code?

Currently, I'm using external console window for debugging code in VSCode, but it's not very convenient while debugging on full screen since it goes into background. The problem with the Debug Console is that it does not allow input, so my program is stuck if it requires any input and I don't use the external console.

Or, is there a way to feed intput into Debug Console?

EDIT: I'm trying to debug C++ code using Microsofts C++ plugin.
Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
        "name": "Debug",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/HelloWorld.exe",
        "args": [],
        "preLaunchTask": "Build",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

Comment: Are you using https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools?  It has an "externalConsole": true; option see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md#externalconsole which may help.

Comment: Yes, I'm usinging that plugin, but for reasons stated in the original post, I don't like using the external console (but I guess that is all I can get for now)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get no external console while debugging C++ files with the following option:
`"externalConsole": false`
within the debugger configuration in the `launch.json` file.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is. You can enable it by adding

```json
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

to your configuration in your `launch.json` file.

Comment: It says: `Property console is not allowed.` - I guess this is not allowed when using C++ debugger. (I should have mentioned my `launch.json`- added to the original post)

Comment: Each particular debugger may or may not support those "console" options.  Apparently the one you are using does not.