# Visual Studio Code Property Console not allowed error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

i am new to programming and i was doing some of these questions of a book.And got stuck in this question about area of a triangle."***Property console is not allowed***".Is it due to the math.h?
Because the same code is fully functional on online-gdb.

[image: Image show's the error]

here is content of lauch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Aside: check that `mult >= 0` before taking `sqrt(mult)` i.e. that it's a real triangle.

Comment: @WeatherVane that would be true if none of them are **negative**.

Comment: @RehanAziz the error does show the `launch.json` as a place where the error happens.

Comment: You might try removing the "console" property in launch.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode - Debuging/Launching using integrated Terminal instead Debug Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903600/vscode-debuging-launching-using-integrated-terminal-instead-debug-console)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala not with sides say 1, 1, 3 which can't make a triangle. The text says "rectangle" in one place but the formula and output is for a triangle.

Comment: oh i tried with 4,5,6 as the sides

Comment: @WeatherVane ah true :D `ENOCOFFE`

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
"console": "externalTerminal"
```

with

```
"externalConsole": true
```

Seems like "console" property is not supported in this version of auto-generated launch.json. However this does the trick to get rid of the warning message for me.

Comment: This is the same solution I arrived at.  I found the solution on the Microsoft article: [Getting Started with GCC](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

Does anyone know what software is responsible for auto generating this launch.json?  I'd like to post an issue or see if there is one already posted.

Comment: Trying `"externalConsole": true,` gives me a similar warning: `Property externalConsole is not allowed.`

Comment: try "terminalKind": "external" or "terminal": "external"

Answer (score 0):

If none of the options worked, try `"terminal": "external"`

Answer (score 0):

Refer this URL https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

> "console": "integratedTerminal"

this one will not open external terminal, and also it will capture input in vscode terminal itself.

Other two values available as of now are :
"internalConsole" and "externalTerminal"